# How to add in-app browsing in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am creating an app where the JSON response contains an URL for the user. If they click on it the browser should display the contents.

I used Linking but it redirects me to external browser.

Is there a way we can do it within the app ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can directly implement this component : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You can push it further by implementing it inside a Modal so you can simply show/hide the modal containing a WebView

Comment: normally you need to set the height of Webview too.

Comment: That example is the one from the official doc ;)

Comment: Not working for me completely

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser) plugin for React Native:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InAppBrowser from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'

class App extends Component {
  async openLink() {
    const result = await InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com', {
      // iOS Properties
      dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
      preferredBarTintColor: 'gray',
      preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
      readerMode: false,
      // Android Properties
      showTitle: true,
      toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
      secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
      enableUrlBarHiding: true,
      enableDefaultShare: true,
      forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
      // Specify full animation resource identifier(package:anim/name)
      // or only resource name(in case of animation bundled with app).
      animations: {
        startEnter: 'slide_in_right',
        startExit: 'slide_out_left',
        endEnter: 'slide_in_right',
        endExit: 'slide_out_left',
      },
      headers: {
        'my-custom-header': 'my custom header value'
      },
    });
  }
}
export default App
```